# How to setup django-celery-beat with multi tenant (django-tenant-schemas) Django application.

Tags: django, celery

I am trying to run celery beat along with celery. Celery works fine with my multitenant Django application (using django-tenant-schemas) with the help of tenant_schemas_celery. But I am not able to run the celery beat as all the scheduled task/periodic task related tables are tenant-specific hence not able to start the celery beat.

Error trace:

```
celery@Amits-iMac.local v4.0.2 (latentcall)

Darwin-17.5.0-x86_64-i386-64bit 2018-05-04 18:20:22

[config]
.> app:         __main__:0x102ef9f28
.> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
.> results:
.> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
.> task events: ON

[queues]
.> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . dataflow.tasks.launch_dataflow
  . datasession.tasks.launch_copy

[2018-05-04 18:20:23,035: INFO/Beat] beat: Starting...
[2018-05-04 18:20:23,166: ERROR/Beat] Process Beat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 42, in __get__
    return obj.__dict__[self.__name__]
KeyError: 'scheduler'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "django_celery_beat_periodictask" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ango_celery_beat_periodictask"."description" FROM "django_ce...
                                                             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/billiard/process.py", line 306, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 613, in run
    self.service.start(embedded_process=True)
  File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 528, in start
    humanize_seconds(self.scheduler.max_interval))
  File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 44, in __get__
    value = obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = self.__get(obj)
  File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 572, in scheduler
    return self.get_scheduler()
  File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 567, in get_scheduler
    lazy=lazy,
  File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_celery_beat/schedulers.py", line 181, in __init__
    Scheduler.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 204, in __init__
    self.setup_schedule()
  File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_celery_beat/schedulers.py", line 189, in setup_schedule
    self.install_default_entries(self.schedule)
  File "/Users/amit/thoughtanalytik/koolanch/src/koolanch/beat_schedulers.py", line 27, in schedule
    self._schedule = self.all_as_schedule()
  File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_celery_beat/schedulers.py", line 195, in all_as_schedule
    for model in self.Model.objects.enabled():
  File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 250, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1118, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch)
  File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 894, in execute_sql
    raise original_exception
  File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 884, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_celery_beat_periodictask" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ango_celery_beat_periodictask"."description" FROM "django_ce...
                                                             ^

[2018-05-04 18:20:23,219: WARNING/Beat] Process Beat:
[2018-05-04 18:20:23,220: WARNING/Beat] Traceback (most recent call last):
[2018-05-04 18:20:23,220: WARNING/Beat] File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 42, in __get__
    return obj.__dict__[self.__name__]
[2018-05-04 18:20:23,220: WARNING/Beat] KeyError: 'scheduler'
[2018-05-04 18:20:23,220: WARNING/Beat] During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[2018-05-04 18:20:23,220: WARNING/Beat] Traceback (most recent call last):
[2018-05-04 18:20:23,221: WARNING/Beat] File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
[2018-05-04 18:20:23,221: WARNING/Beat] psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "django_celery_beat_periodictask" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ango_celery_beat_periodictask"."description" FROM "django_ce...
                                                             ^
[2018-05-04 18:20:23,221: WARNING/Beat] The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
[2018-05-04 18:20:23,221: WARNING/Beat] Traceback (most recent call last):
[2018-05-04 18:20:23,221: WARNING/Beat] File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/billiard/process.py", line 306, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
[2018-05-04 18:20:23,222: WARNING/Beat] File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 613, in run
    self.service.start(embedded_process=True)
[2018-05-04 18:20:23,222: WARNING/Beat] File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 528, in start
    humanize_seconds(self.scheduler.max_interval))
[2018-05-04 18:20:23,222: WARNING/Beat] File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 44, in __get__
    value = obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = self.__get(obj)
[2018-05-04 18:20:23,222: WARNING/Beat] File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 572, in scheduler
    return self.get_scheduler()
[2018-05-04 18:20:23,222: WARNING/Beat] File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 567, in get_scheduler
    lazy=lazy,
[2018-05-04 18:20:23,222: WARNING/Beat] File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_celery_beat/schedulers.py", line 181, in __init__
    Scheduler.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
[2018-05-04 18:20:23,223: WARNING/Beat] File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 204, in __init__
    self.setup_schedule()
[2018-05-04 18:20:23,223: WARNING/Beat] File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_celery_beat/schedulers.py", line 189, in setup_schedule
    self.install_default_entries(self.schedule)
[2018-05-04 18:20:23,223: WARNING/Beat] File "/Users/amit/thoughtanalytik/koolanch/src/koolanch/beat_schedulers.py", line 27, in schedule
    self._schedule = self.all_as_schedule()
[2018-05-04 18:20:23,223: WARNING/Beat] File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_celery_beat/schedulers.py", line 195, in all_as_schedule
    for model in self.Model.objects.enabled():
[2018-05-04 18:20:23,223: WARNING/Beat] File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 250, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
[2018-05-04 18:20:23,224: WARNING/Beat] File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1118, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
[2018-05-04 18:20:23,224: WARNING/Beat] File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch)
[2018-05-04 18:20:23,224: WARNING/Beat] File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 894, in execute_sql
    raise original_exception
[2018-05-04 18:20:23,224: WARNING/Beat] File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 884, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
[2018-05-04 18:20:23,224: WARNING/Beat] File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
[2018-05-04 18:20:23,224: WARNING/Beat] File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
[2018-05-04 18:20:23,224: WARNING/Beat] File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
[2018-05-04 18:20:23,225: WARNING/Beat] File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
[2018-05-04 18:20:23,225: WARNING/Beat] File "/Users/amit/koolanch-dev/dev-1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
[2018-05-04 18:20:23,225: WARNING/Beat] django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_celery_beat_periodictask" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ango_celery_beat_periodictask"."description" FROM "django_ce...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Celery beat (using django_celery_beat)by default connects to public schema and monitors django_celery_beat_periodictask table for the periodic task. Hence we must have these table in public schema. So django_celery_beat app should be part of the public schema and all the periodic task must be created in public schema.

```
with schema_context('public'):
            schedule, created = IntervalSchedule.objects.get_or_create(
                every=execution_interval,
                period=IntervalSchedule.MINUTES)

            pt_obj, created = PeriodicTask.objects.get_or_create(name=name,
                                                             task='tasks.task_name')
            pt_obj.interval = schedule
            pt_obj.enabled = False
            pt_obj.args = json.dumps([])
            pt_obj.kwargs = json.dumps({})
            pt_obj.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a package named `tenant-schemas-celery` available [here](https://github.com/maciej-gol/tenant-schemas-celery) which is recommended by `django-tenant-schemas` itself, which is mentioned [here](https://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use.html#celery).